# Li element goes down after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My problem is that when operating with line_items in mini-cart, updated item goes to the bottom of list, becoming the last one. I guess the problem might be on `<%=j render @cart %>`.

To see what I mean, see [Heroku app](https://sheltered-wildwood-79480.herokuapp.com/store) and try adding some items, and then - increase/decrease the quantity using +/- from the mini-cart.

My code:

[`_line_item.html.slim`](https://github.com/Onidoru/CourseWork/blob/master/app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.slim)

[`_cart.html.slim`](https://github.com/Onidoru/CourseWork/blob/master/app/views/carts/_cart.html.slim)

[`increase.js.erb`](https://github.com/Onidoru/CourseWork/blob/master/app/views/line_items/increase.js.erb)

[`line_items_controller.rb`](https://github.com/Onidoru/CourseWork/blob/master/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb)

Thank you for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in PostgreSQL sorting - by default it sorts by `updated_at` or something like that, so the solution is to add sorting by creation date, for instance, in `cart.rb` model:

`has_many :line_items, -> { order('created_at ASC') }, dependent: :destroy`

It sorts database table by creation date. Never thought PostgreSQL would behave in this way, but from some points of view it seem reasonable.